# How to transfer my Opera speed dial / bookmark from windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, opera

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, and would like to transfer my speed dial/bookmark from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu. I've moved my profile in windows from C: to D:, but can't figure out where is it located in Ubuntu, searched web for sometime, but most of the answers are to use syn, I've tried syn previously, but it messed up with the grouping/order, so I'd like to copy the folder from Windows to Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just export from Opera for Windows and then import into Opera for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I could, but the last time I did, the orders and groupings are gone, so I had to one by one to group them and set them in sequence, that's why I'd like to copy the whole folder as I did in Windows, and it worked well (kept all the groupings and sequences).

Comment: @pomsky, I'm sorry, my bad, I just exported from Opera Windows in HTML format and imported into my Ubuntu, it seems kept all the groupings. I'm not using Opera in Ubuntu due to freeze problem when some sites trying to open additional ad browsers in Opera.

Comment: how do I post as answer? I can't see this option anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I just exported from Opera Windows in HTML format and imported into my Ubuntu, it seems kept all the groupings. I'm not using Opera in Ubuntu due to freeze problem when some sites trying to open additional ad browsers in Opera.